# BigQuery - remove duplicate rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with duplicate rows (sometimes 2,3,4 duplicates) and I need to delete them by leaving only one row (they are all the same, no dates differences).
Is there another way than CREATE OR REPLACE as recommended by Google?
I've already tried with CTE, ROW_NUMBER() over partition, ... but haven't found a way for the moment

Let's say the table looks like this:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test |
| 1 | test |
| 1 | test |
| 1 | test |

Comment: what is wrong with `CREATE OR REPLACE ...`? this is the way to go! you just do something like `SELECT DISTINCT ...` and either creating new table w/o duplicates or replacing original one

Comment: what if I needed to daily schedule this operation and the table was used by an application? Would it still be the best way?

Comment: sure. why not - obviously assuming that application is duplication aware and solves it on its side :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete duplicate information with some steps without using the create or replace clauses.

I’m using this example data:

```
select * from `items`
```

[image]

You can follow these steps:

1.Insert the data that you don’t want to delete and mark it with ‘--’ or use the character you want.

```
insert into `items` (id, data)
select distinct id,concat(data,'--') from `items`
```

[image]

2.- Delete all the data that is not marked in this case with ‘--’

```
delete   from `items` where STRPOS(data,"--")=0;
```

[image]

3.- Update the data deleting the mark we used in this case ‘--’

```
update `items` set data = substring(data,0,LENGTH(data)-2) where 1=1 ;
```

[image]

Comment: I don't need to delete redundancy in the output, I need to clean the table

Comment: @FedericoSala can you share the output you expect, please. So i can change my answer.

Comment: I need to have in the table only one row of the above, I'm not trying to select any data